# Adicionar via linha de comando aplicativo em "Aplicativos Inicias de Sessão"

Tags: ubuntu, linha-de-comando

Como adiciono um aplicativo em "*Aplicativos Iniciais de Sessão*" via **terminal** no *Ubuntu*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, uma forma de fazer isso sem usar a UI, é colocar o atalho (com extenção **.desktop**) do seu software na pasta `~/.config/autostart/`, tudo que estiver dentro desta pasta será executado na inicialização da UI. Você pode criar um arquivo **.desktop** dessa forma:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=my Unipro UGENE
GenericName=Integrated Bioinformatics Suite
Comment=Unipro UGENE is a cross-platform visual environment for DNA and protein sequence analysis.
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=/home/samuel/ugene-1.11.5 ./ugene -ui -c %F
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/ugene.svg
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Categories=Utility;Development;
StartupWMClass=UGENE
```

Veja mais sobre arquivos .desktop em: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application

Essa é única forma de fazer isso sem usar a UI que eu conheço, espero ter ajudado.

PS:
Caso o que você quer é inicializar um serviço na inicialização do sistema (não necessariamente da UI), dê uma olhada sobre os [Daemons e Init Scripts](https://www.calculate-linux.org/main/en/initscripts).

Comment: Resolveu! ao usar o UI, é aí que são colocados os comandos adicionados em aplicativos de sessão.